# Mongoid has_and_belongs_to_many without arrays?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I can see, under some circumstances, the usefulness of using Mongoids has_and_belongs_to_many calls in their native state. However, the situation I am in is dire.

We have two collections: categories, and products.

You can see where this is going. A category has and belongs to many products, and vice versa.

At first this worked fine. It was not until we started working with hundreds of thousands of documents that we started to see huge, seemingly exponential, decreases in performance.

In this case, as much as I don't want to admit it, I think the old fashioned RDMS way had it right. I'd rather have a "join collection", as I feel it must be faster to do it that way, than to be storing arrays of 100s or even 1000s of products in each Category document.

So,

- If my intuition is just totally incorrect (I am new to Mongo), please informatively correct my mistake
- If this sounds correct, please let me know how I might go about achieving such an idea

I can't find much information about this issue other than that other people have achieved what I'd like to do (they give no examples, no code, not even a point in the right direction).

Has anyone encountered this issue? Any ideas, or any good resources on this topic, that you know of?

**EDIT:** I should throw in, for some background info, that the way I discovered this was by running and watching our script. The script adds products to categories based on our files. I noticed that adding one page of products/category went very fast, but page 2+ went slower, and slower, etc. I looked into this for the last hour or two, on Google, and found that, indeed, it must be the fact that we have these n-to-n arrays, which is what Mongoid defaults to. I need to find a faster way, as this simply cannot work.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be relatively simple. It didn't solve the issue of speed entirely, but it works in our case. Simply research indexing in MongoDB.